# Combine bytes php

Tags: php, byte

I need equivalent of this part (in C++), but on PHP:

```
unsigned char arr[ 2 ];
arr[ 0 ] = 0x04;
arr[ 1 ] = 0x00;
unsigned short shape_types;
memcpy( &shape_types, arr, 2 )
```

Maybe somebody knows a program, where i can combine bytes and see result in Hex and Dec?

Comment: SO is not a site where people do your work for you. You need the code - you hire a developer.

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP manual as a starting point, or are you just hoping someone will give you teh codez?

Comment: I don't wait exactly answer from somebody. I just want to understand how combine 2 bytes.

Comment: So in the end the result should be numerical? (0 to 65535) In your example 0x04 "+" 0x00 = 0x0400 = 1024? `$shape_types = (0x04 << 8) + 0x00;` or you can actually just write it directly as `$shape_types = 0x0400;` .. I must not be getting it.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have given is not directly applicable to PHP.

PHP lacks the typing or ability to move data directly from one memory location to another to do this.

I guess what you want is pretty much the following.

Your input is an array of bytes: (Include up to 4 bytes for 32 bit systems, up to 8 for 64 bit)

```
$bytes = array(
    0x04,
    0x00
);
```

You can reduce it with a loop:

```
$result = 0;
foreach ($bytes as $byte) {
    $result = $result << 8 | $byte;
}
```

Or with `array_reduce`:

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $bytes,
    function ($out, $in) {
        return $out << 8 | $in;
    }
);
```

Or even just combine the values directly:

```
$result = $bytes[0] << 8 | $bytes[1];
```

Display it in hex:

```
var_dump(dechex($result));
```

Output:

> string '400' (length=3)